# Display characters on a square grid?

Tags: linux, bash, vim, fonts, fixed-width

How can I display characters as if they are square in vim? The characters themselves don't need to be square, but if you were to draw a grid through all centre points of the characters it should make a square grid.

I would like to do this because I am designing a fortress layout for [Dwarf Fortress](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/). The game is set out on a square/cube grid.

Comment: Are you using VIM in a terminal session?  You can configure the terminal to use a square font rather than vim if so, which one is it?

Comment: Yes, I am using bash 4.2.10.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows there are some square monospaced fonts in conhost.exe (which is the default terminal used by cmd and PowerShell) by default like the 8x8 font, but I've never heard of one in Linux. I did a search and found the [square](http://strlen.com/square/) font which were **made exactly for your purpose**

> **[Square is a TTF font intended for roguelike games](http://strlen.com/square/)**
>
> Roguelike games consist entirely of text in *grid cells*, but the problem is that ***most monospaced fonts are a lot higher than they are wide***, which means roguelikes either have non-square cells, or they have square cells and the characters don’t take up the entire box, neither of which looks very aesthetically pleasing.
>
> **Square has been designed to make characters fill a square space as evenly and uniformly as possible.** It is inspired upon the way Japanese characters always evenly fit a box, no matter their design. It foregoes the typical ascenders/descenders in lowercase characters, and instead makes lowercase characters look like a lighter version of uppercase characters.

[image: Square font]

Cross-site duplicates:

- [Name for type that has the same width and height](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/45260/81481)
- [Examples of “square” fonts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/48823/81481)

I've also found many other fonts on the same category although I didn't have a chance to test them

- http://www.1001fonts.com/monospaced+square-fonts.html
- http://www.fontspace.com/category/mono,monospace,square
- http://www.fontspace.com/category/mono,square,monospaced

[image: square fonts example]

---

However if your texts are limited to a *small character set* (specifically ASCII 21 to 7E plus a few East Asian characters) then you can just use [full-width form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms) directly without the need of another font

Below is a small shell script to do the conversion from halfwidth to fullwidth. The string to convert is read from standard input

```bash
halfwidth='!"#$%&'\''()*+,-.\/0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~｟｠¢£¬¯¦¥₩ '
fullwidth='！＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－．／０１２３４５６７８９：；＜＝＞？＠ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ［＼］＾＿｀ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ｛｜｝～｟｠￠￡￢￣￤￥￦　'
sed -e "y/$halfwidth/$fullwidth/"
```

Example

```
$ cat square.txt
0123456789
1-square 8
2####text7
3$$$$$$$$6
4@@@@@@@@5
5(SQUARE)4
6~~~TEXT 3
7>>>2
8////\\\\1
9876543210

$ cat square.txt | sh fullwidth.sh
０１２３４５６７８９
１－ｓｑｕａｒｅ　８
２＃＃＃＃ｔｅｘｔ７
３＄＄＄＄＄＄＄＄６
４＠＠＠＠＠＠＠＠５
５（ＳＱＵＡＲＥ）４
６～～～ＴＥＸＴ　３
７＜＜＜＜＞＞＞＞２
８／／／／＼＼＼＼１
９８７６５４３２１０
```

The result may not be perfect squares in many cases due to the font, so you may still need to check for a font with square fullwidth characters on your system if the aspect ratio doesn't fit your requirements

Answer (score 2):

Create a square mono-spaced font from Courier using your favourite font-editor. Use that in your Terminal.

If you lack the patience for font editing and have charisma (or something) you can do [this](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2012/01/simple-font-editing/) instead.

The intertubes suggested [this](http://theflavor.com/2009/08/07/nice-square-monospaced-font/) to me but maybe it isn't really square.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a font to use with the [python QR code generator](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/).  It seem that this library assumes a precise height:width character ratio of 8:7, so the square fonts above actually produced a QR code wider than it was tall.  On my Mac, the Andale Mono font at a point size of 14 or 28 produces perfectly square QR codes.  In the [iTerm](https://iterm2.com/) window shown below, for example, the QR code is exactly 168:168.

[image]